# Error: Execution failed for task app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting this error when I'm going to build apk.

> Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3

Here's the screenshot of the error

[image: enter image description here][1]]

[image]

Comment: add build.gradle file

Comment: This issue could be due to a couple of reasons, mostly duplicate/ conflicting dependency. Post your build.gradle files and run the ./gradlew allDependencies task to get an overview of the dependency tree.

Comment: 1) your CardView library is the incorrect version and doesn't match the other support libraries 2) You've compiled too many Google Play Services

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved by using multidex. By adding `multiDexEnabled true` in defaultConfig and `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'`
 in dependencies in build gradle in app and adding `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"` in manifest. Check out screen shots [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSvm1.png):[image: Manifest]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Cg5d.png):[image: u can use dexOptions and packagingOptions]